# Complete() empty columns in r for time series (Tidyr)

Tags: r, time, tidyr

I'm having difficulty using the Tidyr function "complete()" to fill in columns for absent weeks. While the complete() function does work, it loops through the entire year 35 times and fills in 4,375 entries rather than just 125.

In short, when I try to use the complete function, it does not just complete the dataframe but duplicates all columns 35 times.

I have tried several different approaches including with and w/o the full_seq function.

*1st approach:*

```
   Df %>%
      group_by(week = week(`Local Start Time`)) %>%
      complete(week = 1:52)
```

*Second approach:*

```
   Df %>%
      group_by(week = week(`Local Start Time`)) %>%
      complete(week = full_seq(week <- c(1:52), 1L))
```

I expected the dataframe to stop at row 125 but instead the complete() loops over the entire yearly data (35 times!) and continues until column 4375.

[image: Ideally, it would stop at row 125.]

Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

The data I used is here...

```
structure(list(`Local Start Time` = structure(c(1483846399, 1483846519, 
1483851979, 1484734742, 1485017522, 1485190862, 1486236902, 1486238462, 
1486347422, 1486448822, 1487221742, 1487392502, 1487449502, 1487678750, 
1487679111, 1487679411, 1487683370, 1488321651, 1488745130, 1489353950, 
1489710710, 1491043550, 1492036467, 1492105535, 1492150284, 1492180823, 
1492772358, 1493428578, 1493440398, 1493465717, 1493476518, 1493484558, 
1493495837, 1493622558, 1493639598, 1493718078, 1493718858, 1493720778, 
1495021772, 1495598357, 1495599017, 1496175677, 1496428517, 1496439678, 
1496494637, 1496632757, 1496887457, 1496887757, 1496888117, 1497031577, 
1497207557, 1497318797, 1497368657, 1497491178, 1497558017, 1497857478, 
1498220117, 1498245977, 1498246577, 1498255277, 1498257797, 1499203517, 
1499470577, 1500752057, 1500899837, 1502036477, 1502392277, 1502410817, 
1502428157, 1502429957, 1503492618, 1503500417, 1503507318, 1503672677, 
1503674057, 1503674370, 1503675077, 1503923478, 1503928037, 1503932777, 
1503943037, 1503972019, 1503989537, 1504383497, 1504421837, 1504639337, 
1504656977, 1504672937, 1504682418, 1504722677, 1506766878, 1507180518, 
1507184597, 1507228877, 1507229657, 1507370717, 1508326217, 1508343977, 
1508357297, 1508374397, 1508492838, 1508555177, 1508560158, 1508868737, 
1509231244, 1509252184, 1509845644, 1510709818), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), week = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 
6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 13, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 
17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22, 
22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25, 
25, 25, 27, 27, 29, 30, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 
34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 39, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 43, 43, 44, 45, 
46)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -108L), .Names = c("Local Start Time", 
"week"))
```

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: @Sotos Thanks for the advice. I added the data I used.

Comment: Have you tried your first approach without the `group_by`?

Comment: @markus It worked- Thanks! I had to rework the entire visual analysis though...